# How to pass arrays of strings to another function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass the random strings I've generated from a certain function to another.

I want the strings generated on the function `inputAccounts()` to be passed on the function `viewAllRecords()`.

The strings generated from the function `inputAccounts()` are contained in an array and I want them to still be in an array when passed to the function `viewAllRecords()`.

Here is my program:

```
int randomNumber(int min, int max);
char randomString(char *str, int randomCharCount);

int numOfAccounts;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    showOptions();
}

int randomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    max -= min;
    return (rand() % max) +min;
}

char randomString(char *str, int randomCharCount)
{
    const char *charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < randomCharCount; i++)
    {
        str[i] = charSet[randomNumber(0, 61)];
    }
}

void showOptions()
{
    char choice;
    system("cls");
    printf("System");
    printf("\n[1] Sign up Account");
    printf("\n[2] View Records");
    printf("\n[3] Exit");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    getchar();
    chosenOperation(choice);
    showOptions();
}

void inputAccounts()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char rStr[9] = {0};     // sStr is where the rStr are saved .
    char sStr[50][9];       // max 50 rStr
    randomString(rStr, 8);
    strcpy(sStr[numOfAccounts],rStr);
    printf("Random String Generated: %s\n", sStr[numOfAccounts]);
    numOfAccounts++;
    getch();
}

void chosenOperation(char choice)
{
    if(choice == '1')
    {
        inputAccounts();
    }
    else if(choice == '2')
    {
        chooseViewType();
    }
    else if(choice == '3')
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void viewAllRecords()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char rStr[9] = {0};     // sStr is where the rStr are saved .
    char sStr[50][9];       // max 50 rStr
    int i = 0;  
    system("cls");
    while(i < numOfAccounts)
    {
        randomString(rStr, 8);
        strcpy(sStr[i],rStr);
        printf("Random String Generated: %s\n", sStr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void chooseViewType()
{
    system("cls");
    int choice;
    printf("[1] View All Records\n");
    choice = getch();

    if(choice == '1')
    {
        viewAllRecords();
    }
    getch();
}
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: If `char *` is a pointer to a character (array) then you could try `char **` which is a pointer to a pointer of a character (array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand what you want to do, the `inputAccounts()` function should generate a single random string and the v`iewAllRecords()` function should list all the random strings generated. The array sStr is defined **inside** the function `inputAccounts()`, so it isn't available to the function `viewAllRecords()`. You should move the array in the global section of the code or define it static. You may try something like this:

```
int randomNumber(int min, int max);
char randomString(char *str, int randomCharCount);

int numOfAccounts;
char sStr[50][9];       // String storage array defined globally

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    showOptions();
}

int randomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    max -= min;
    return (rand() % max) +min;
}

char randomString(char *str, int randomCharCount)
{
    const char *charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < randomCharCount; i++)
    {
        str[i] = charSet[randomNumber(0, 61)];
    }
}

void showOptions()
{
    char choice;
    system("cls");
    printf("System");
    printf("\n[1] Sign up Account");
    printf("\n[2] View Records");
    printf("\n[3] Exit");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    getchar();
    chosenOperation(choice);
    showOptions();
}

void inputAccounts()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char rStr[9] = {0};     // sStr is where the rStr are saved .
    randomString(rStr, 8);
    strcpy(sStr[numOfAccounts],rStr);
    printf("Random String Generated: %s\n", sStr[numOfAccounts]);
    numOfAccounts++;
    getch();
}

void chosenOperation(char choice)
{
    if(choice == '1')
    {
        inputAccounts();
    }
    else if(choice == '2')
    {
        chooseViewType();
    }
    else if(choice == '3')
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void viewAllRecords()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;  
    system("cls");
    while(i < numOfAccounts)
    {
        printf("Random String Generated: %s\n", sStr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void chooseViewType()
{
    system("cls");
    int choice;
    printf("[1] View All Records\n");
    choice = getch();

    if(choice == '1')
    {
        viewAllRecords();
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C when functions are invoked, the variables declared in that function are created on the "stack" and this stack is automatically deleted when the function returns. In inputAccounts you define the arrays on the stack when means they don't exist when the function returns. You ned to define the array on the "heap" using dynamic memory allocation such as calling "malloc". This will enable you to pass the address between functions.